# Any way to retrieve the representation form from a list of Arabic Unicode codepoints in Java

Tags: java, unicode, arabic

In Arabic each letter has four representations based on the surrounding letters. For more information: [Arabic Script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script), [Arabic in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) and [Unicode 6.2.0 Chapter 8](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch08.pdf)

I am looking for an algorithm implementation, or OS library that given an array of Arabic codepoints can calculate the representation forms that would be used to render the text (isolated, middle, etc).

I am not looking to render the text itself so a low level library like java.awt.font won't help. I also tried using ICU4J but I can't find how I could extract the information.

Any ideas before I go off to implement my own solution?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround that could work. Using ICU4J and the ArabicShapping class you can convert the codepoints from the 06XX codeblock to the FEXX codeblock. The FEXX codeblock contains the information about the form. A bit of a stretch so maybe it would be better if we implemented the joining algorithm as defined in the Unicode standard.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you are rendering Arabic text you don't actually change the Unicode codepoints, you just map each character to a glyph in your chosen font and then apply OpenType substitution features to change each glyph to the desired form. The relevant OpenType features are "medi", "init", "fina", and "isol".

But the platform font rendering should handle this for you, so what is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Based on rendering some Arabic characters can be confused with others. I was working on an IDN library which given an Arabic string return all strings that could be confused with the original. The context is that of an internet registry.

Comment: Maybe one of the cases is for rendering in terminal :D